# Split string only once between sequence of letters and sequence of numbers

Tags: php, regex, string, substring, text-parsing

I want to extract two substrings from a predictably formatted string.

Each string is comprised of letters followed by numbers.

Inputs & Outputs:

- `MAU120` => `MAU` and `120`
- `MAUL345` => `MAUL` and `345`
- `MAUW23` => `MAUW` and `23`

Comment: Would we ever have a number without letters, or letters without numbers?

Comment: Does it always start with MAU and end with a number like your examples? It's more helpful if you can specify a general pattern rather than random examples.

Comment: Consider this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031055/php-explode-from-first-number-integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$matches = array();

if ( preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$/i', 'MAUL345', $matches) ) {
    echo $matches[1]; // MAUL
    echo $matches[2]; // 345 
}
```

If you require the `MAU` you can do:

```
/^(MAU[A-Z]*)([0-9]+)$/i
```

Removing `i` modifier at the end will make the regex case-sensitive.

Comment: Also matches `mAuL345` and `bob2`.

Comment: OP never stated that `MAU` was a requirement, nor case. I've edited my answer to show a way to require `MAU` and added info about the case modifier.

Comment: Sorry @webbie. I wasn't criticizing your approach. I was merely pointing out some matches that the OP didn't specify by example. The problem is that the OP didn't say much of _anything_ concerning the desired pattern. Nevertheless, this is a much better answer than it was. +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
/(\D*)(\d*)/
```

PHP code:

```
$matches = array();

var_dump( preg_match('/(\D*)(\d*)/', 'MAUL345', $matches) );
var_dump( $matches );
```

Comment: That looks dangerous. . . "?@#!123" now parses. . .

Comment: `?@#!123` will be parsed as `?@#!` and `123`.  That probably introduced characters that will correctly parse that are not intended by the OP.  Hence, looks dangerous.

Comment: The OP just says "the substring from string before first number occurs" (title) -- the examples specifically use letters, but the question itself does not exclude them...

Answer (score 1):

Taken literally from your examples:

```
<?php
$tests = array('MAU120', 'MAUL345', 'MAUW23', 'bob2', '?@#!123', 'In the MAUX123 middle.');

header('Content-type: text/plain');
foreach($tests as $test)
{
    preg_match('/(MAU[A-Z]?)(\d+)/', $test, $matches);
    $str = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';
    $num = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : '';
    printf("\$str = %s\n\$num = %d\n\n", $str, $num);
}
?>
```

Produces:

```
$test = MAU120
$str = MAU
$num = 120

$test = MAUL345
$str = MAUL
$num = 345

$test = MAUW23
$str = MAUW
$num = 23

$test = bob2
$str = 
$num = 0

$test = ?@#!123
$str = 
$num = 0

$test = In the MAUX123 middle.
$str = MAUX
$num = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

When you can guarantee that there will be one or more non-numbers and then one or more numbers, you can call upon `sscanf()` to parse the string.

The native function has multiple advantages over `preg_match()`.

1. It doesn't return the fullstring match.
2. It will allow you to type cast substrings depending on the format placeholder you use.
3. It can return its array or create reference variables -- depending on the number of parameters you feed it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qqr55))

```
$tests = [
    'MAU120',
    'MAUL345',
    'MAUW23',
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    sscanf($test, '%[^0-9]%d', $letters, $numbers);
    var_export([$letters, $numbers]);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output: (notice that the numbers are cast as integer type)

```
array (
  0 => 'MAU',
  1 => 120,
)
array (
  0 => 'MAUL',
  1 => 345,
)
array (
  0 => 'MAUW',
  1 => 23,
)
```

If your numbers might start with zero(s) and you want to retain them, you can use `%s` instead of `%d` to capture the non-whitespaces substring.  If you use `%s`, then the digits will be cast as a string instead of int-type.

Alternative syntax: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FC3cm))

```
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_export(sscanf($test, '%[^0-9]%d'));
    echo "\n";
}
```